# Symfony ManyToMany query getting segmentation fault

Tags: php, symfony

I have a specific problem that I tried everything but can't find a way to fix it.
I am having this error ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE on the browser and in the apache error_log 
[Thu Sep 08 16:07:55.896191 2016] [core:notice] [pid 834] AH00052: child pid 844 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)

My code :

```
class Trainer
{

       /**
       * @var integer
       *
       * @ORM\Column(name="trainer_id", type="integer")
       * @ORM\Id
       * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
       */
       private $trainerId;

       /**
       * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Unit")
       * @ORM\JoinTable(name="trainer_unit",
       *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="trainer_id", referencedColumnName="trainer_id")},
       *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="unit_id", referencedColumnName="unit_id")}
       * )
       */
       protected $units;

       public function __construct()
       {
              $this->units = new ArrayCollection();
       } 
}
```

The problem started when I tried to use

```
 $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
 $trainer = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Trainer')->find($id);
 dump($trainer); //no errors


 dump($trainer->getUnits()); // *** ERROR 
 //or 
 $trainer->getUnits()->add($unit); // *** ERROR
```

I am using PHP 5.5, Symfony 3, AMMPS 3.5

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

you get the error because $trainer can be a result set.
You need to then iterate through it.

Try this:

```
foreach( $trainer as $t ){
    dump( $t->getUnits() );
}
```

I think it should work, but no guarantees.

**EDIT #2** Based on comments.

Can you try this as well to see if the result is different:

```
$repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Trainer');
$trainer = $repository->find($id);
```

**EDIT #3** Based on comments.

```
dump($trainer)
TrainerController.php on line 104:
   Trainer {#704 ▼
     -trainerName: "Gisele"
     -trainerId: 2
     #units: PersistentCollection {#751 ▼
       -snapshot: []
       -owner: CletTrainer {#704}
       -association: array:19 [ …19]
       -em: EntityManager {#522 …11}
       -backRefFieldName: null
       -typeClass: ClassMetadata {#706 …}
       -isDirty: false
       #collection: ArrayCollection {#752 ▶}
       #initialized: false
     }
  }
```

---

```
  dump($trainer->getUnits())
```

The clet.localhost.com page isn’t working

clet.localhost.com didn’t send any data.
ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Same apache error

**EDIT #4**

clet.localhost.com is my domain, where my /web is linked to.
I am trying to update a trainer, where I placed the dump to figure out the problem

[browser error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lKcdM.png)

[apache error - error_log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ctUW.png)

Comment: Sorry, that is not the problem.
Also does not work when I use

$form = $this->createForm(TrainerForm::class, $trainer);

If the form does not have the units, work fine

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? It seems you have additional code you haven't shown us in the post.

Comment: Hi Alvin, sorry.

I want to achieve, Many units for a Trainer, or many trainers to a unit.

The $trainer is not a result set, is a Trainer object.

Comment: What I was trying to say, does not matter if I am manipulating the the $trainer, or a Form Object. If the Form object needs to access the getUnit the error happen in the same way

Comment: I edited my post. Can you try my second suggestion to see what happens. I think that at least should work, otherwise there is something else wrong.

Comment: I edited your post, #3 with the tests related to your sugestion

Comment: I don't knw if makes any difference but my computer is OS X El Capitan

Comment: What is `clet.localhost.com` page? Are you using routes? Where exactly do you see the ERR_EMPTY_REPONSE? I'm looking for answer so I can help, but there's a lot that is not clear. Can you clarify everything?

Comment: Hi again, edit #4 with more explanation. Thanks again for your time

Comment: This is beginning to look like a configuration issue. Possibly Apache configuration? So my guess is you are using virtualhosts?

Comment: Alvin, why would be a apache configuration if dump($trainer); die; in the  the controler updateAction works and get the error in dump($trainer->getUnits()); die; 
does not make any sense to be a apache problem

Comment: I just found this: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/2EDWkwK2Go8  Is it possible you haven't updated Chrome. Have you tried different browsers? Or tried a browser on a different machine. I seen a lot of searches related to Mac as well. What is the Error number?

Comment: Yes, already tried in safari and firefox before posting the problem

Comment: [core:notice] [pid 834] AH00052: child pid 6097 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)